# How to find the first X gb of data?

Tags: disk-usage, file-copy

I've been trying to find a way to free up some space on a drive by moving folders to another. I have a folder full of stuff I can move, doesn't need to be all of it, to free up some space.

In Windows I'd just select a bunch of folders, get the properties, it'd tell me how much space it was taking up, I'd select more or less and then move them. I can't do that from a bash terminal, and I have no idea how to go about it. Google searching keeps leading me down the path of moving all files over a certain size, which isn't what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you run `mc`?

Comment: If not a dupe, at least related: [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a GNU system, you could script it as:

```
#! /bin/bash -
usage() {
  printf >&2 '%s\n' "Usage: $0 <destination> <size> [<file1> [<file2>...]]"
  exit 1
}
(($# >= 2)) || usage
dest=$1
size=$(numfmt --from=iec <<< "$2") || usage
shift 2
(($# == 0)) && exit
selected=()
sum=0

shopt -s lastpipe
LC_ALL=C du -s --null --block-size=1 -- "$@" |
  while
    ((sum < size)) &&
      IFS= read -rd '' rec &&
      s=${rec%%$'\t'*} &&
      file=${rec#*$'\t'}
  do
      selected+=("$file")
      ((sum += s))
  done

((${#selected[@]} == 0)) ||
  exec mv -t "$dest" -- "${selected[@]}"
```

Used for instance as:

```
that-script /dest/folder 1G *
```

To move as many files as necessary from the expansion of that `*` glob to make up at least 1GiB.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm after, but I'm getting du: write error. It's doing the job, but is that error avoidable?

Comment: @Tod, I can't reproduce it. What operating system are you using? You can always redirect  *all* the errors of `du` to `/dev/null` (`du 2> /dev/null` instead of `du`).

Comment: @Tod, I can reproduce with older versions of GNU `du` but only if I ignore the SIGPIPE signal (as in `(trap '' PIPE; du -s /bin/*) | head -n 1`). SIGPIPE should not be ignored under normal conditions though. what do you get if you run `grep SigIgn /proc/self/status`?

Comment: I'm using Slackware 14.2. the result of that command: SigIgn: 0000000000001000

Comment: @Tod, yes, it seems you have SIGPIPE ignored, which is wrong. It would be worth investigating how you ended up in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could pretty much do the exact same thing within the terminal:

First execute `cd /path/to/full/drive/` to get into the filled up drive's root folder.

Then, to view the capacity taken by each folder inside that drive you could use `du -hd1` (assuming the GNU implementation of `du`).

Explanation: `du` (Disk Usage) runs recursively on your file tree from current folder, printing the capacity used by each folder. By default it's printed as number of 512-byte units or kibibytes (depending on whether POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment which is somewhat unreadable), and so the `-h` option tells it to print sizes as "human readable" (converted to MB/GB). The `d` parameter forces `du` to stop its descent into the file tree after reaching the specified "depth" (in this case 1).

Once you find a specific directory you'd like to move content from you could use `ls -lh` to view file sizes inside this directory to identify specific files to move. Here the `h` is once again for printing sizes as "human readable", and `-l` is to get the "long" format which includes file sizes.

Bonus point: You could pipe `du` into `sort` (here again assuming GNU `sort`) to get the output sorted by size (assuming the file names don't contain newline characters) to make things easier like so:

```
du -hd1 | sort -h
```

and `ls` can sort the output by size as well when providing the `-S` option:

```
ls -lhrS
```

Finally, to move files/folders you can use the `mv /path/to/source /path/to/target` command.

I'm assuming that you know what is the root folder of the relevant drive.

Comment: On Linux, and some other Unices, `ls -lS` will sort by size.  Your pipeline `ls -lh | sort -h` would _not_ sort by size.

Comment: @Kusalananda, `ls -S` is now POSIX. `ls -h` is not (neither are `du -h`, nor `du -d1` all GNU extensions, nothing to do with Linux).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, `ls -S` is POSIX. I'm not keeping updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `du -hd1`

-h prints size in human readable format

-d <1> is the depth for directory.

Example:

```
$ du -hd1 
11G     ./dir1
9.5G.   ./dir2
11G     ./dir3
6.3G    ./dir4
9.1G    ./dir5
6.4G    ./dir6
4.8G    ./dir7 
58G     .
```